# Did Gelfand prove that every commutative Banach division algebra is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, division-algebras

On [this MSE page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368456/frobenius-from-hurwitzs-theorem/1876922#comment9805432_1876922), an answer mentions a cornucopia of vaguely similar results to Hurwitz's Theorem and Frobenius' Theorem, all of which say something like "Every XYZ division algebra is isomorphic to something in this small neat set." often consisting of an initial segment of $\mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb{C}\subset\mathbb{H}\subset\mathbb{H}$.

However, the answer mentions a "Gelfand Theorem" from 1939 which says "the commutative Banach division algebras are $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$". Presumably this isn't true as is - do we have to assume they are real algebras? Even then, I can find no mention of this online or on Wikipedia etc. when it feels like it would be an incredibly important result to mention...

**Does anyone know what this result actually said and can find a reference for it?**

Comment: Why do you think it isn't true? Google for "Gelfand–Mazur theorem".

Comment: In fact, if you Google for "commutative division Banach algebra", which is the obvious thing to do, you get there...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez While googling as you suggest doesn't actually bring up the Gelfand-Mazur theorem (my google account must affect my search results?) the theorem is exactly what I wanted. Thank you - a little silly as a question as you say!

Comment: It is not a silly question! But in this time and age one has to hone one's googling foo every day to keep it in good shape!